# Expected Committer Name Git Push Issue

Tags: git, push

I'm trying to commit/Push some code to GIT, but when I tried to commit the code using SourceTree it gave me an error:

```
remote: Push rejected.[K
remote: 
remote: refs/heads/Branch Details: 6a5d6d4cdd53db591e53db78c51225a619af487f: expected committer name 'Your Name Complete' but found 'Your Name'[K
remote:
```

Commit is done, but code is not pushed to remote.

I just noticed in the Global setting that my was "Your Name" and I changed it (TO: Your Name Complete)  in Global configuration, also verified the name in `Tools --> Options` and its showing "Your Name Complete" now.
I also tried:

```
git config --global user.name "Correct User Name"
git config --global user.email "your@email.com"
```

but still unable to Push the changes, still the same error can any one help me to push the code to remote repository?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following the example of [this blog post](http://www.mattshelton.net/2015/08/12/changing-the-author-of-a-single-tag-in-git/) (it was for a tag, in your case it is for a branch HEAD), you would need to amend at least just the branch HEAD you want to push:

```
git commit --amend --allow-empty --author="LastName, FirstName <name@email.com>"
```

And then push.

Comment: I did -- (master)
$ git commit --amend --allow-empty --author="Lastname, Firstname <email@emc.com"
  But got error --
fatal: No existing author found with 'Lastname, Firstname <email@emc.com'
   
--Need help..

Comment: @voraD Can you try with a final `>` at the end before the closing `"`? `<email@emc.com>" `

Comment: nice , this one helped me, some companies use username and  author both , so you need to do this git commit as per @VonC  and then you can git push from your tools as well - like intellij

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully, if user may reset/revert the local commit and then recommit the code after correcting the name in global configuration, this will make the push successful. Here is a way to revert commit:

```
git reset HEAD~1  -- revert changes made to the index (i.e., that you have added)
```

For now, I tried the empty commit and also tried to commit the same file with some space (to attempt a fake commit) but both (above solution and fake commit) did not work for me. Then I just removed the cloned repository and re cloned it and then committed the code again and this time Push was done successfully, as I already changed the name in configurations.

Comment: That should work too, although I always managed to directly amend the commit as I mentioned in my answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Posting this answer as I faced a similar issue today and the suggestions provided in other answers for this topic didn't worked for me. Here is what I did to resolve the issue:

a) Verified that user.name and user.email were as expected for local and global git file

Local  Git config file -> name 'config', No extension, stored under'.git' directory of local repo folder

Global Git config file -> No name, just extension , named '.gitconfig', stored inside user's profile folder like "C:\Users\yourusername" folder

This was fine.

b) My previous commit was pushed successfully. So, I compared the previous git push and the new git push. I observed that with the new git push I was trying to push more than one commits and though of combining it to single commit. After the commits were combined, I was able to push my changes successfully.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

1. To check what the commiter name is in local

   `git log --pretty=fuller @{u}..HEAD`
2. Make changes as per global

   `git config --global user.name "FirstName Lastname"`

   `git config --global user.email "FirstName.Lastname@domain.com"`
3. This changes only the new commits so to regenerate the commits try to push updated meta

   `git commit --amend --reset-author`

now git push should work

Comment: Step 3 is a particularly nice trick.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, reverting the changes, and then updating the git config and recommitting worked for me.