# Git push rejected due to expected committer email

Tags: git, git-push

Tried to push a local branch with a bugfix to the origin and got message like:

```
remote: Push rejected.
remote: refs/head/bugfix/issueX: hash1hash2hash: expected committer email 'a@email.com' but found 'z@email.com'
remote: refs/head/bugfix/issueX: hash1hash2hash: expected committer name 'A' but found 'Z'
```

The computer is a "shared" test/dev device and 'A' was the previous user. I changed email and name with

```
git config --global user.name "Z"
git config --global user.email "z@email.com"
```

The remote server is running Atlassian Stash.
Already tried [Expected Committer Name Git Push Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008916/expected-committer-name-git-push-issue)

Comment: Can you alter settings of the repo on the server? It probably has an email checking hook that is unwanted for you (unlike the linked question).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. The repo on the server has a commit checker which checks that the committer email and name are equal to the Stash server user's name and email. I have already checked my user name and email, all ok.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The `.git-credentials` did not contain the user Z but the user A and some older ones. For some reasons it did not ask for the credentials of Z. I removed the existing file and pushed to origin again then git asked for the credentials.

Comment: A little hint: If you're working on a shared computer, I wouldn't use `git config --global`. I would set git config via `git config user.name = "Z"` and `git config user.email "z@email.com"` for the current repository.