# Expected committer issue — when doing git push

Tags: git, push, commit

so my issue is a difference between the expected committer and the actual committer.

When I try to push, it will say:

> Expected committer name "XXXXXX" but found "YYYYYY". Expected
>   committer name "XXXXXX's email" but found "YYYYYY's email".

My name and email are the ones git "found", I do not know why it's expecting somebody else to do the commit/push.

My **git config --list | grep user** will display the correct information "YYYYYY" and "YYYYYY's email".

I have tried pushing with `**--amend --reset-author**` or `**--amend --author="YYYYYY <YYYYYY's email>"**` and even `**--allow-empty**` but it always ends with the same result, I cannot do the push unless I edit my global configs and say that I'm another user which would be false.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Where are you pushing to? It may be the remote repository. Rejecting the push, because the commits were done by wrong id.

Comment: I'm pushing to a repository on bitbucket, to a branch that I was asked to create, and since it hasn't worked so far, I've been creating and deleting the branch, trying to get the commit to push with MY name.

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled git and it still won't work, expects the same committer which isn' me

Comment: The problem is most likely that your administrator set your Bitbucket account to expect someone *else's* name on your commits. You cannot fix this yourself, unless you are the administrator. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/28425670/1256452 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/47799872/1256452

Comment: I agree with @Torek. Is the IDs found in the error message, the ones you expected, and the expected ones unexpected?

Comment: I found the problem, it was in Windows Credentials Manager. I had used a coworker's account to push my changes at first, because they still hadn't created mine. Now they did, and i had the same issue, and ten i found out about CM and changed it there... I was expecting my coworker's email account and user name because they were the ones registered in there.